# Update nginx configuration file using a script

Tags: nginx

Input:

[image: Source file]

I want to write a script name nginx-conf-update.sh.
when is run

`$./nginx-conf-update.sh 3`

Output:

[image: the output will be]

Comment: What exactly do you want this script to do?

Comment: What's the significance of the argument you are passing?

Comment: I want to replace all text inside upstream myproject { .... } with     upstream myproject {
    server 192.168.0.3:8000;
    server 192.168.0.4:8000;
    server 192.168.0.5:8000;
  }
if I run $./nginx-conf-update.sh 3 output file should be like given one. 
If I run $./nginx-conf-update.sh 4 output file should be 
upstream myproject {
    server 192.168.0.3:8000;
    server 192.168.0.4:8000;
    server 192.168.0.5:8000;
    server 192.168.0.6:8000;
  }
It starts from 192.168.0.3 till 192.168.0.n.

Comment: I have setup some docker container. Nginx load balancer distributes the session to those containers. I want to write script that will scale the container as much as I want and add to the load balancer.